# Is there any JS library can create a new Ethereum address from a password as input parameter?

Tags: accounts, javascript

In geth console we can create a new address like this:

```
personal.newAccount("my-password")
```

I'm looking for a library which can create a new account with my password without any Ethereum node.

Comment: If you are going through with this, you should require a large minimum number of characters. Otherwise, it would be easily brute-forced. :-)

Comment: You should be aware that geth does not use the password to generate the address, it is always randomly generated. The password only is used to encrypt the generated private key. Also brain wallets are [considered not very secure](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41618/why-are-brain-wallets-not-secure-people-keep-saying-it-but-explain-to-me-why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keythereum can do it

```
const path = require("path")
const keythereum = require("keythereum")

const dk = keythereum.create()
const password = "WhenLambo"
const keyObj = keythereum.dump(password, dk.privateKey, dk.salt, dk.iv)
console.log("keyObj", keyObj)

const keystoreDir = path.join(__dirname, "../data")
keythereum.exportToFile(keyObj, keystoreDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyethereum, ethjs, lightwallet and theses are not alone.

Check before asking! Google, Github... there is plenty of ressourve and library to generate account in differents way.